# Problems in html displaying text

Tags: html, css, text, resolution

I have a website, and I have a problem that text doesn't display correctly. It varies, I think according to screen resolution, but I have no idea why.

Any idea why is this happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/948DD/ here is the source code

```
<body>
<div id="navwrap">
    <div id="nav" align="center">
        <ul>
            <img src="img/notify_icon.png"/>
            <li><a href="#top">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#p04">FEATURE SET</a></li>
            <li><a href="#whoareweclick">WHO ARE WE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#divider5">INDIEGOGO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#href">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="welcome" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="tr01">
            <td id="td01">
            <p id="p01">Hi.</p>
            <p id="p02">welcome to the webpage of</p>
            <p id="p03">NOT!fy</p>
            <p id="p04">the best solution against annoying notifications</p>
            </td>
            <td id="td02"><img src="img/notify_big_icon.png"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="divider" align="center">
    <img src="img/divider_with_arrow.png"alt="divider" id="dividerpng"/>
</div>

<div id="featureset_chrome" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="chrometr">
            <td id="chrometd01"><img src="img/featureset_chrome.png"/>
            </td>
            <td id="chrometd02">
            <p id="chromep01">feature set</p>
            <p id="chromep02">- a world first solution to get rid of annoying notifications</p>
            <p id="chromep03">- you just need a Google Chrome extension and our app installed on your mobile device and you are good to go</p>
            <p id="chromep04">behind the scenes</p>
            <p id="chromep05">the Chrome extension watches which sites you are currently viewing and mutes the matching applications on your phone</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    <div id="divider2" align="center">
    <img src="img/divider_points.png"alt="divider" id="dividerpointspng"/>
</div>

<div id="per_app_muting" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="perapptr">
            <td id="perapptd01">
            <p id="perapp_p01">per app muting</p>
            <p id="perapp_p02">- forget the annoying notifications (e.g.: game notifications) </p>
            <p id="perapp_p03">- with our sleek UI you can easily pick the applications which you rather want to be muted</p>
            </td>
            <td id="perapptd02"><img src="img/per_app_muting.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    <div id="divider3" align="center">
    <img src="img/divider_points.png"alt="divider" id="dividerpointspng"/>
</div>

<div id="quiet_hours" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="qhtr">
            <td id="qhtd01"><img src="img/quiet_hours.png"/>
            </td>
            <td id="qhtd02">
            <p id="qhp01">quiet hours</p>
            <p id="qhp02">- set your cycle to turn on silent mode for your smartphone in specific time intervallum </p>
            <p id="qhp03">- no more awkward moments because of your ringing phone</p>
            <div id="whoareweclick"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="divider4" align="center">
    <img src="img/divider.png"alt="divider" id="dividerpng"/>
</div>

<div id="whoarewe" align="center">
    <p id="whop1">Who are we? </p>
    <p id="whop2">Two passionate and determined boy who believe that they can change the way how the Android notification system works.</p>
    <p id="whop3">We live in Hungary and attend university in Budapest.</p>
</div>
<div id="whopics" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="whotr">
            <td id="whotd01"><img src="img/kerdojel.png"/>
                <p id="name"> bendegúz </p>
                <p id="descr"> 18 yrs <br />
                our spokesman <br />
                also good at: <br />
                html, css <br />
                </p>
            </td>
            <td id="whotd02"><img src="img/kristof.png"/>
                <p id="name"> kristóf </p>
                <p id="descr"> 19 yrs <br />
                owner of the idea <br />
                responsible for: <br />
                design <br />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="whopics2" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="whotr">
            <td id="whotd01"><img src="img/kerdojel.png"/>
                <p id="name"> X Y </p>
                <p id="descr"> we are looking for an android developer, if you are brave enough to join our startup, then head over to "Contact us" section
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="divider5" align="center">
    <img src="img/divider.png"alt="divider" id="dividerpng"/>
</div>

<div id="indiegogo" align="center">
    <p id="indiep1">Indiegogo </p>
    <p id="indiep2">As we are students, we don't own a big amout of equity.</p>
    <p id="indiep3">That is why we decided to crowdfund our idea at Indiegogo.</p>
    <p id="indiep4">We find it the best way to get noticed and be able to get funded.</p>
    <p id="indiep5">Soon a pitch video will be released.</p>
    <p id="indiep6">our state at the moment:</p>
    <p id="ourstate"><img src="img/ourstate.png"/></p>
</div>
</div>
    <footer id="footer">
           <p>Copyright: NOT!fy 2014, development and design by: Kristóf Dombi,     Máté Bendegúz Kovács</p>
</footer>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#navwrap {
z-index:10;
}

#contentwrap {
padding-top:92px;
z-index:5;
}

#nav {
font-family: Century Gothic;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #353539;
height: 100px;
width: auto;
font-weight: bold;
border-width:0px;
opacity:0.95;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
#nav ul {
margin:0 auto;
width:auto;
height:100px;
margin-bottom:
}
#nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0px;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
border-right:1px solid #DDD;
height: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav ul li {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d2d2d2;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
margin-bottom: 90px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #d2d2d2;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 0px;
}


#nav ul li a:hover {
color: #ffd200;
}

#nav img{
    width:100px;
}

body
{
background-color:#c5c5c5;
}

#welcome {
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:20px;
}

#tr01 {
height:300px;
}
#td01 {
text-align:left;
vertical-align: top;
}

#td02 {
text-align:right;
}

#td02 img {
width:200px;
margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#p01 {
text-decoration:none;
color:#3c3c40;
font-family: Roboto, thin;
font-size:60px;
font-weight:300;
margin-top: 30px;
}

#p02 {
text-decoration:none;
color:#3c3c40;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size:30px;
font-weight:300;
}

#p03 {
text-decoration:none;
color:#3c3c40;
font-family: Roboto condensed;
font-weight:400;
font-size:35px;
margin-top:7px;
margin-bottom:7px;
}

#p04 {
text-decoration:none;
color:#3c3c40;
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight:300;
font-size:15px;
}

#featureset_chrome {
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
}

#chrometr {
height:450px;
}

#chrometd01 {
text-align:left;
vertical-align: top;
width:450px;
}

#chrometd02 {
text-align:right;
margin-left:0px;
width:400px;
}

#chrometd01 img {
width:300px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#chromep01 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:50px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#chromep02 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#chromep03 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#chromep04 {
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:35px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#chromep05 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#per_app_muting {
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
}

#perapptr {
height:450px;
}

#perapptd01 {
text-align:left;
vertical-align: top;
width:450px;
}

#perapptd02 {
text-align:right;
margin-left:0px;
width:400px;
}

#perapptd02 img {
width:300px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#perapp_p01 {
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:35px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#perapp_p02 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#perapp_p03 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#quiet_hours {
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
}

#qhtr {
height:500px;
}

#qhtd01 {
text-align:left;
vertical-align: top;
width:450px;
}

#qhtd02 {
text-align:right;
margin-left:0px;
width:400px;
}

#qhtd01 img {
width:300px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#qhp01 {
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:35px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#qhp02 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#qhp03 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#whoareweclick {
padding-top:200px;
}

#whoarewe{
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
text-align:left;
}

#whop1 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:50px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#whop2 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#whop3 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#whopics {
width:600px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
text-align:center;
}

#whotr {
height:250px;
}

#whotd01 {
text-align:center;
vertical-align: top;
width:300px;
}

#whotd02 {
text-align:center;
margin-left:0px;
width:300px;
}

#whotd01 img {
width:200px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#whotd02 img {
width:200px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#name {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:40px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#descr {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#desctd01 {
text-align:center;
vertical-align: top;
width:320px;
}

#desctd02 {
text-align:center;
margin-left:0px;
width:320px;
}

#divider5 {
margin-top:50px;
}

#indiegogo{
width:850px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:40px;
text-align:right;
}

#indiep1 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:50px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#indiep2 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#indiep3 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#indiep4 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#indiep5 {
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:100;
font-size:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#indiep6 {
font-family: Roboto;
color:#3c3c40;
font-weight:300;
font-size:30px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom:30px;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#ourstate {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}

#ourstate img {
width:600px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#footer {
background-color: #353539;
height:50px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:0px;
opacity:0.95;
}

#footer p {
color:#d2d2d2;
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight:300;
font-size:17px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:17px;
}
```

Comment: We can't diagnose CSS from images.

Comment: "I don't post html or css"... oh, the actual things we need to see to try and work out what the issue is?  That's a shame. Vote to close

Comment: It looks like the font rendering is different on the two computers -- maybe you are using different browsers or different operating systems.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/948DD/ here is the website source code, I'm sorry, I thought you could give me suggestions

Answer (score 0):

A broad answer to your question:

This is the result of [type hinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) and the rendering quality based upon display. Generally speaking Windows does not anti-alias text to the extent that, Mac OS X does. That means that the type will not be "smoothed" using sub-pixels or surrounding pixels causing the type to look jagged.

This is compounded when a font is not hinted, which is the tedious task of hand picking pixels that will be used in font rendering at each individual size. When this is compounded with the lack of anti-aliasing you may miss actual pieces of your letter forms!

This is further compounded if you are looking at a monitor with a smaller number of pixels.

Try and find a hinted version of your font, try using a larger size, or perhaps using a different font all together.

Comment: So the problem is with the roboto font I am using? It's from google fonts, in different weights

Comment: Yeah, try increasing the weight and try creating a greater contrast between the type and the background.